# What's a word that captures the sentiment of "inside looking outwards"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm attempting to title a paper I'm writing about the traditions of a certain group of people; and my analysis is focused on what these traditions mean to them, and how they see others interpret their traditions...

I've been trying to come up with a phrase or a word that captures that sentiment, because *An Inwards Looking Outwards Analysis of X* sounds awkward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An outwards looking in analysis could be described as **introspective**, so you could say an inwards looking out analysis is **extrospective**.

*An extrospective analysis of X*

Comment: This may be true, but I have to say I've never seen the word used anywhere.  Is it common in technical publication?

Comment: I haven't seen it in technical publication as such, but I have seen it included on several dictionary sites and there's a topic on Typology Central about extrospection which includes a definition of it in the OP.

Comment: Both great answers I didn't think of using - but this is the one I went with!

Answer (score 3):

Endogenous attitudes or sentiments of a group of people; as opposed to exogenous ones.

http://escholarship.org/uc/item/79d936s0#page-86
Structures of Sentiment
Mapping the Affective Bases of Social Relationships
Thesis: by Gervais, Matthew M